# accordion using pure angularjs without css

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to hide detail of others and show the detail of the current clicked name

http://jsbin.com/tewegahobi/edit?html,js,output

```
<li ng-click="showDetail = true"  ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}
       <span ng-show="showDetail == true">{{item.detail}}</span>
      </li>
```

Not sure I'm doing it right, I'm able to click to show the detail, but it doesn't hide others' detail when I clicked on particular name.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it so that only one name displays at a time by monitoring which item has been clicked with `scope`. Then you can also use `scope` to define a function to use with `ng-click` so that when that user clicks on an item that value changes. Each item has it's `ng-show` attribute to only show an item if it matches the item that was previously selected by the user.

```js
function TodoCrtl($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{name:"James",detail:"something of James"},{name:"John",detail:"something of John"}]

  // Holds the mame of the item clicked by the user.
  $scope.chosen = '';

  // This function is activated each time the user clicks on an element
  // with 'ng-click' that is associated with this funciton.
  $scope.setChosen = function(itemName) {
    $scope.chosen = itemName;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>ng-click</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<div ng-controller="TodoCrtl">

 <li ng-click="setChosen(item.name)"  ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}
   <span ng-show="item.name == chosen">{{item.detail}}</span>
  </li>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure this is what he wants... He would like to have only one detail shown at the time, I think.

Comment: @Mike yes but is it possible not to have a function in the controller level?